# Apache Spark: Master removed our application: Failed when using saveAsTextFile on large RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm loading a file of 20 GB in Spark Standalone mode on a machine with 4GB RAM and 2 cores, do some processing and then try to save the result (for testing purposes) to a text file using saveAsTextFile.

If I manually extract only a few thousand lines from the original input file and run the code on that, it works like a charm, resulting in the expected part-xxxxx files.

However, if I provide the whole 20GB file as input, it will start off fine, then hang somewhere along the process and when let run overnight it will have failed in the morning with the following message:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o219.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Master removed our application: FAILED
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a few issues here, but the most commons would be :

- Too many file opens killed the process
- The serializer you're using (by default the Java serializer) might create a GC Overhead  - try switching to Kryo Serializer (c.f. Spark's documentation : Tuning page)
- finally you're running out of disk.

Now without any idea of what your computation is or the logs from the actual server, it's difficult to tell what happened.

Comment: Thanks, Olivier, for your reply. I will try switching to the Kyro serializer. I put the log of the master here: http://pastebin.com/LWa9VgVi and the log of the worker here: http://pastebin.com/AS1LH7Vk.

The problem seems to be "Master: Application PySparkShell with ID app-20150429142649-0005 failed 10 times; removing it"
The performed computation is the reading in of a 20GB csv file, a sort, a groupby and a count to determine the number of entries for each month. The problem occurs with: data.saveAsTextFile("stats").

Comment: There should be additional logs somewhere, maybe your pyspark job doesn't have the necessary libraries on all the workers ?

Comment: I'm currently using only one machine with one worker connected to the master to play around a little bit. So all logs should be on the server. Is spark saving logs at other places than the logs directory within the spark path?